# Null Reference Exception when using NeatUpload

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, neatupload

When we run this line:

```
    Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.ProgressInfo progress = GreyBoxProgressBar1.ProcessingProgress = new Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.ProgressInfo(1, "");
```

We get this exception:

> Timestamp: 22.10.2010 12:27:00
>   Message:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.    at
>   Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadModule.SetProcessingState(String
>   controlUniqueID, Object state)    at
>   Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.ProgressInfo.UpdateProcessingState()
>   at
>   Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.ProgressBarBase.set_ProcessingProgress(ProgressInfo
>   value)

The GreyBoxProgressBar1 is not null.

Anyone know why this occurs?

Comment: You probably haven't configured a module.

Comment: @Pieter, that was it, where you configure the module varries between casini and IIS. You should put that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason I didn't add it as an answer was because this was an extremely wild guess from the code fragment you see below. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't configured a module.

This is the code of the method that throws:

```
public static bool SetProcessingState(string controlUniqueID, object state)
{
    return InstalledModule.SetProcessingState(controlUniqueID, state);
}
```

From http://neatupload.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e3955728d259#dotnet%2fsrc%2fBrettle.Web.NeatUpload%2fBrettle.Web.NeatUpload%2fUploadModule.cs.